# Is there a way to implicitly define a function midprogram in fortran'

Tags: function, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

I am trying to solve some eigenvalue problems. I am using gfortran. I have written a module that contains the `bisection_method` subroutine. In my program, I defined the `secular(m,x)` function that takes a 2D array `m` and a float `x` and outputs the characteristic polynomial of `m` at `x`; i.e. det (m - x Id). One of the arguments of the `bisection_method` subroutine is a function `f`, which was intended as a function of one real input and real output. I would want to input, however, the 'partially applied' function `secular(m,_)` to this subroutine. Is there a way to do this, without explicitly defining this function in a module?

I can't define this functions explicitly, for I am to do this procedure for several matrices `m`. ALso, I cannot modify the body of the `bisection_method` because I use it for function of one real argument as well. Is there a way around this in Fortran?

Comment: Do you mean like a [_closure_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9692697/3157076)?

Comment: @francescalus precisely

Comment: isn't it possible to pass a wrapper internal procedure of the form 'f(x)' (that references 'm' via host association) to 'bisection_method()' as an argument?

Comment: @roygvib I solved it defining a wrapper function with parameter `m`, and added a setter subroutine.

Answer (score 2):

As @francescalus pointed out, you want to have a closure for your problem.

Closures are partially supported in Fortran by using internal procedures, because the internal procedure has access to all variables in the surrounding scope.¹

Assuming that you want to find the eigenvalues of `M` with your code it could be structured like this.²

```
module bisection_and_linalg
    use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
    integer, parameter :: wp = real64
    implicit none(type, external)

    abstract interface
        real(wp) pure function real_function(x)
            real(wp), intent(in) :: x
        end function
    end interface

contains

    !> Find the root of f in the interval I
    real(wp) pure function bisect(f, I)
        procedure(real_function) :: f
        real(wp) :: I(2)
        ...
    end function

    !> Evaluate the characteristic polynomial of m at x
    real(wp) pure function secular(M, x)
        real(wp), intent(in) :: M(:, :), x

        ...
    end function

    !> Get eigenvalues
    real(wp) pure function eigenvalues(M)
        real(wp), intent(in) :: M(:, :)

        ...

        ! n.b. here you can use the bisection method to
        !   find your eigenvalues.
        bisect(f, ...)

    contains

        real(wp) pure function f(x)
            ! n.b. here you have your closure.
            !   M is captured from surrounding scope.
            f = secular(M, x)
        end function
    end function

end module
```

---

¹ The only caveat is, that internal procedures only exist as long the surrounding scope exists. So it **is unfortunately not** possible to write a generic function that takes a function and returns a function pointer to a partially applied version of it by using internal procedures. But this is not a concern for your problem.

² Perhaps it would be better to return an actual characteristic polynomial. Then you could derive it, to use e.g. Newton-Raphson instead of bisection.